# CKEditor prevent closing tags

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have couple of CKEditor fields to manage responsive emails from admin

Let's say

**Email Header**

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>
     ...Header contents...
   </td>
  </tr>
```

**Email body**

```
  <tr>
   <td>
     .. Some email content ..
   </td>
  </tr>
```

**Email footer**

```
  <tr>
   <td>
     ...Footer contents...
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The Header contains all html tags and opening `table` tag

Footer have closing `table` tag

But CKEditor close `table` in `header` to make it valid and breaks my layout. How do I prevent it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to disable tag validation in ckeditor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769409/how-to-disable-tag-validation-in-ckeditor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [ticket #9597](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9697), the option to disable auto-correction of open tags is not available.

Comment: That's pretty sad. Do you know about Tinymce or something similar to it? It's still an huge paid for moderators and other people far from development to edit raw html in textboxes

Comment: @SergeyKhmelevskoy You may have better luck asking that as another question.